# Autofixture.NSubstitute check received calls without freezing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute, autofixture

I have a `sut` with the dependency:

```
public interface IDep
{
  void Click(int c);
}

public class Sut
{
  public Sut(IDep dep)
  {
    dep.Click(10);
  }
}
```

in my test I want to check that `Click` was called, but it does not work without being frozen.

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(
  new AutoNSubstituteCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true }
);

//fixture.Freeze<IDep>(); // uncommenting this line make it working
fixture.Create<Sut>();
fixture.Freeze<IDep>()
       .Received(1)
       .Click(Arg.Any<int>);
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: get rid of the first `Freeze` call. To reduce the count of lines

Comment: Keep first line and pass value to variable. Perform assertion on variable after exercising sut

Answer (score 0):

> in my test I want to check that Click was called, but it does not work without being frozen.

That is by design. That freeze line is necessary to capture a single mocked dependency.

In this case the dependency injected into the SUT and the one you try to get after with the freeze will be different instances. Which is why your particular test case fails.

I would suggest keeping the first line and pass the returned value to a variable. You can then perform your assertion on the variable after exercising the SUT in this particular case.

For example

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(
  new AutoNSubstituteCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true }
);

//Arrange
IDep dependency = fixture.Freeze<IDep>(); 
//...any configuration needed on the mock can be done here

//Act
Sut sut = fixture.Create<Sut>(); //frozen dependency will be injected into sut.

//Assert
dependency.Received(1).Click(Arg.Any<int>);
```

I suggest reviewing the [Quick Start](https://autofixture.github.io/docs/quick-start/#) to get a better understanding of what is the purpose of the `Freeze` functionality

> Luckily we can tell our fixture to “freeze” a particular type. This means that every time we request an instance of a frozen type, we will get the same instance. You can think of it as registering a singleton instance in an IoC container.

Comment: In most cases it is acceptable to have all dependencies "frozen" by default. while reducing the count of lines can be more benficial

Comment: @deeptowncitizen In this case the dependency injected into the SUT and the one you try to get after  with the freeze will be different instances.

Comment: do you mean that each `Freeze` call will recreate the entire instance hierarchy of members?

Comment: @deeptowncitizen every call to Freeze<T> creates a singleton for the lifetime of the particular fixture for that type.

Comment: from https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/1064 it looks like Freeze does not override anything by design. So I can call `Freeze` as a singleton from any point of the code and the arrangement will not change

Comment: @deeptowncitizen the behavior you are trying to achieve, based on the provided example, can't be done without first freezing the dependency. I would suggest raising an issue on the Github if you think that is a bug.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. I think there can be some customization that can help to achieve such behavior. and was wondering is it known customization, etc